# AudioTrack AudioRecord android issue, silence

Tags: android, multithreading, service, audiorecord, audiotrack

Do anyone know if there is a need for audiorecord and audiotrack to be seperated in a special way/type of thread, runnable, service etc for it to be able to work together? Now I can start an audiotrack, then audiorecord without issues.

But if I start and stop the audiotrack while recording the audiorecord starts to output 0's as if it was muted. (But it is not muted or stopped)

If I start the audiorecord then the audiotrack then the audiorecord is also "muted".

Also weird is it that when I unplug and plug in my wired headset it will start recording/output recording other than 0's again (which makes me think my phones Lenovo B and Lenovo C2 is too cheap(circuit/hardware issues) or have build issues) but I do not know.

Anyone heard of this issue with a suddenly "muted" audiorecord or an audiorecord which responds to unplug/plugging of a wiredheadset without having any settings/methods applied for it?

---

Code update

```
class myRecordAndPlayer(){

public void initiateRecorder() {
    if(audio.getMode()!=AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL) {
        audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
        //audio.setSpeakerphoneOn(false); for mode in com (mode in com produces more echo/crosstalk)
    }

    rec = true;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
            AudioRecord audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) * 10);
            try {
                audioRecorder.startRecording();
                while (rec) {
                    bytes_read = audioRecorder.read(buf_audio, 0, buf_audio_len);


public void initiatePlayer() {
    if(!play) {
        play = true;
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
        Thread receiveThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AudioTrack track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, BUF_SIZE, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
                track.play();
                try {
                    while(play) {
                        track.write(bufToPlay, 0, bufToPlay.length);
```

Comment: show the code (initialization, start, stop, etc)

Comment: @VolodymyrKulyk Ok I did :)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested.

```
private Thread audioRecordThread
private AudioRecord audioRecorder;
private AudioTrack audioTrack;

public void initialize() {
    audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, BUF_SIZE, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

    audioRecorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLE_RATE,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLE_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT) * 10);

    audioRecordThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                writeAudioDataToAudioTrack();
            }
        });
}

public void start() {
    audioTrack.play();
    audioRecorder.startRecording();
    audioRecordThread.start();
}

private void writeAudioDataToAudioTrack() {
    while(AudioRecord.RECORDSTATE_RECORDING == audioRecord.getRecordingState()) {
        audioTrack.write(bufToPlay, 0, bufToPlay.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for code. Do you mean it will help to put everything except initialize in private? I thought that was an access related declaration?

Comment: No, just try this code, private or public depends on you

Comment: I know that the recording state is always positive, even if the problem occurs, as I have a failsafe for a stopped recorder, which should force start again, but it never stops and never gives true on muted. It just starts outputing 0's like it is muted
But I will configure my code to have a constructor with both record and track and have RECORDSTATE_RECORDING == audioRecord.getRecordingState() in while() to see if it changes anything then get back to you!
I also have a mediaplayer that initializes now and then and plays a alarm, and that has no effect on the audiorecord. thanks again